# Logstash with rabbitmq cluster

Tags: rabbitmq, cluster-computing, logstash

I have a 3 node cluster of Rabbitmq behind a HAproxy Load Balancer.  When I shut down a node, Rabbitmq successfully switches the queue to the other nodes.  However, I notice that Logstash stops pulling messages from the queue unless I restart it.  Is this a problem with the way rabbitmq operates?  i.e. it deactivates all active consumers.  I am not sure if log stash has any retry capability.  Anyone run into this issue?

Comment: I'm having same problem, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Quoting rabbit mq documentation, page for [clustering](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html) first

> What is Replicated? All data/state required for the operation of a
>   RabbitMQ broker is replicated across all nodes. An exception to this
>   are message queues, which by default reside on one node, though they
>   are visible and reachable from all nodes.

and [high availability](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html#cancellation)

> Clients that are consuming from a mirrored queue may wish to know that
>   the queue from which they have been consuming has failed over. When a
>   mirrored queue fails over, knowledge of which messages have been sent
>   to which consumer is lost, and therefore all unacknowledged messages
>   are redelivered with the redelivered flag set. Consumers may wish to
>   know this is going to happen.
>
> If so, they can consume with the argument x-cancel-on-ha-failover set
>   to true. Their **consuming will then be cancelled** on failover and a
>   consumer cancellation notification sent. It is then the consumer's
>   responsibility to reissue basic.consume to start consuming again.

So, what does all this mean:

- You have to mirror queues
- The consumers should use manual ACK
- The consumers should reconnect on their own

So the answer to your question is no, it's not a problem with rabbitmq, that's simply how it works. It's up to clients to reconnect.

Comment: A very well presented answer.  Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Did it help you or solve your problem perhaps? If neither could you say what's missing, or unclear ?

Comment: Your answer explained the workings of rabbit.  However, log stash issue still remains.

Comment: Well is logstash connecting to the load balancers IP? Are the queues mirrored?

Comment: Yes.  The queues are HA replicated.